# Sharing only a single folder on windows 7 starter

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, desktop

I want to share a single folder located on my desktop, and sync it via SyncToy to another pc on the network.
However, when I make it a shared folder, the 'users' folder also becomes shared. Altough such access still requires a login, I would rather not have the 'users' folder be shared, just that one single folder.
I do not recall anymore how I shared it the first time. After noticing the behavior, I went to the 'Network' menu located on the start menu, browsed to computer's folder, chose the users folder, selected properties, sharing, advanced sharing and unchecked 'share this folder'. Upon doing so, the folder I actually wanted to share still remained in the network location, however it would be inaccessible from other PCs in the network.
I then left clicked on the folder on the desktop, chose properties, sharing, "share" (not advanced sharing) and confirmed by pressing "share" again. (I apologize if the names are mistaken, my version of windows is localized)
This resulted in the Users folder showing up again, and the target folder being available.

Is the automatic sharing caused by having the folder on the desktop, or is it just the way Windows 7 works?
Is this caused by having windows 7 Starter?
Is there a way to share a single folder and not all of it's parent folders too?
The linked to TechNet article seems to confirm this is intended behavior, however it refers to "using the shell UI" is there another way of doing it, so it's not triggered? The article says no, but maybe there is a command line way around it?
Anyhow, in the meantime I will just move the folder to C:/, which has worked, without exposing the 'Users' folder.

Comment: Welcome to super user. Please edit your question to describe the exact steps you're taking to share the folder (as there are more than one ways to do so). Welcome and good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7: "Users\Default" accessible remotely](http://superuser.com/questions/67511/windows-7-users-default-accessible-remotely), specifically see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/322180/23133)

Comment: Added the specific steps taken.